# post submit button php

Tags: javascript, php

I really don't know why the submit funktion doens't work. I really try to solve the Problem. Does anybody have a idea why this doen't work?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo ("submit funkt");
}
else{
    echo ("submit funkt nicht");
}
?>

<form action="" method="get">
<div role="main" id="task-form-fill" class="ui-content">
    <label for="text-basic">Titel:</label>
    <input type="text" name="titel" id="titel" value="<?php $titel ?>">
    <label for="textarea">Beschreibung:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="beschreibung" id="beschreibung" value="beschreibung"></textarea>
    <label for="date">End-Datum:</label>
    <input type="date" name="enddatum" id="datum" value="enddatum">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Prioritaet:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="prio" id="radio-choice-c" value="hoch" checked="checked">
            <label for="radio-choice-c">Hoch</label>
            <input type="radio" name="prio" id="radio-choice-d" value="mittel">
            <label for="radio-choice-d">Mittel</label>
            <input type="radio" name="prio" id="radio-choice-e" value="niedrig">
            <label for="radio-choice-e">Niedrig</label>
    </fieldset>
   <button name="submit" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: instead of button, use `<input type="submit" name="submit />` note the type of the input

Comment: change `method="get"` to `method="post"`

Comment: If you don't  <echo ("submit funkt");>  you have a prob in your html page ,   you form must be Post in your code

Comment: we changed the method to post but it still doesn't work

and the idea to use button instead of input does't work too.

Answer (score 0):

please mention type= "submit" for button

```
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: and change the form method to post

Answer (score 0):

As other people have mentioned, if you want this to submit the form you should have the following:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
```

However, the reason your form is not working is the top line. Change

```
<form action="" method="get">
```

To

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

And then it will work.

Comment: change echo ("submit funkt"); to die ("submit funkt"); instead. I've tested your code on my machine and it works fine. Killing the code with the error message will make sure the text is not appearing where you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form on button click button type should be Submit.

```
<input type='submit' name="submit" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="submit" value='Submit'/>
```

Thanks.
M